# How to install flutter_svg and drawing_animation together

Tags: svg, flutter-dependencies, svg-animate

I have an app were i want to use animated and non animated SVG files. For non animated SVG i'm using [flutter_svg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg) package.Looking for animated SVG support, i found [drawing_animation](https://pub.dev/packages/drawing_animation) package, but when i'm trying to install it, i get the following error:

```
C:\path\to\test_svg_app> flutter pub add drawing_animation
Because drawing_animation >=1.0.0 depends on path_parsing ^0.2.1 and drawing_animation <1.0.0 depends on path_parsing ^0.1.3, every version of 
drawing_animation requires path_parsing ^0.1.3 or ^0.2.1.
And because flutter_svg >=1.0.0 depends on path_drawing ^1.0.0 which depends on path_parsing ^1.0.0, drawing_animation is incompatible with flutter_svg >=1.0.0.
So, because test_svg_app depends on both flutter_svg ^1.0.3 and drawing_animation any, version solving failed.
pub finished with exit code 65
```

Is there a way to solve this dependency problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use both packages like this in your pubspec.yaml file. So only compatible versions of both these packages will be picked.

```
drawing_animation:
flutter_svg:
```